# Can a student propose a different programming language for the assignment or Lab?

Tags: computer-science

Suppose, someone is taking a course that requires a programming language to be known by the student.

Suppose, the course is [*Optimization*](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLDFB2EEF4DDAFE30B). The teacher proposes **MATLAB/Octave** to be the programming language of choice. However, the student that we are talking about doesn't know MATLAB/Octave. So, he proposes the teacher allow him to use another programming language, say, **Python**.

What should the teacher do in this case? Should he allow the student to use Python, or should he tell the student to stick to MATLAB/Octave?

Explain why.

Comment: Are you the teacher or the student in this scenario?

Comment: Can you just ask the question without all the hypotheticals? What's wrong with "I'm taking Optimization and my prof wants me to use MATLAB/Octave ..."

Comment: @elrond, Student.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him-, Coz, this incident took place 6 years ago.

Comment: So, "I took optimization and my prof wanted me to ..."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, do not ask it here, ask your teacher.

It depends on what the aims of the course are. If it is part of the aims to teach MATLAB (for example, because later courses will build on this knowledge), then the answer you will get is a "no, sorry" - if you are lucky you even get the reason why not. However, if the programming language is irrelevant for the course requirements, it is possible you will get permission to use something else.

As a teacher, I did allow my students to hand in their assignments using different software but I warned them that, if they get stuck, I will not be able to help them. I had a few students who chose this option, they all asked it individually.

And a final point: also consider that it could be beneficial for you to learn a new skill.

Comment: ... and if the professor says no, don't just use Python anyway. Speaking from long, sad experience.

Answer (score 15):

That's up to the professor. Maybe the professor knows that a lot of the work to be done for this course is well supported by existing Matlab packages but that there are no good Python packages. Or the other way around and the professor wants students to implement things from scratch, rather than just use black box methods.

It's also possible that the professor just doesn't know any other programming language and wants to be able to give thorough feedback on student submissions.

You can certainly propose using a different programming language. Whether or not the professor allows you to do so, who knows.

Answer (score 7):

Many novice programmers regard 'their' language with religious-like fervour. They gather/communicate with fellow enthusiasts, they evangelise to those who use other languages, they read books and journals with 'Python' (or whatever) in the title: it becomes an important part of their self-identity.  They support their chosen language just as some support their chosen football team.

They have to grow out of this phase.  For a 'python progammer' to write a MATLAB program is not a betrayal, an act of apostasy. A programmer needs to know several languages, so they can adapt to different problems and different situations.

Being a student is supposed to be about learning new stuff, not sticking with the comfort of what you know. This student should seize the opportunity to learn a second programming language.